# Hyperplane and dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to prove the following:
V is a Vectorspace

$dim V = \infty \Leftrightarrow \exists$ a linear Bijection from $V$ to a Hyperplane of $V$.

Have no idea to start this.

Comment: Start with a basis.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean?

Comment: I mean, you wrote that you have no idea how to start on the problem. And I'm saying, the way to start is with a basis for $V$. You know what a basis for a vector space is?

Comment: Of course this requires the Axiom of Choice somehow.  Existing answers use a basis, which follows from AC.  How about: can we do this without using a basis, using say Zorn's Lemma directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition $\dim V=\infty$ means that there exists an infinite basis $\mathcal{B}=\{e_i\}_{i\in I}$ of $V$. As $I$ is an infinite set, if we choose a finite subset $J\subset I$ we still have $|I|=|I\setminus J|$ and thus there exists a bijection $\phi:I\to I\setminus J$. Now define $f:V\to V$ by the formula
$$
f\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_{i_k}e_{i_k}\right):=\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_{i_k}e_{\phi(i_k)}.
$$
As every element $v\in V$ has a unique representation in terms of $\mathcal{B}$, this is a well defined function. Furthermore it is clearly linear, injective (since $\phi$ is a bijection), and with range
$$\text{Span}\{e_i\}_{i\in I\setminus J}\subsetneq V.$$

We have thus constructed a linear bijection from $V$ to a **proper vector subspace of $V$** (the concept of hyperplane doesn't have so much sense in the infinite-dimensional case).

Comment: Ok, thank you. But this is only in one way? $dim V = \infty \Rightarrow$ linear bijection?

Comment: The other way is trivial; if $V$ were finite dimensional we would have $\dim V=\dim \text{Im} f+\dim\ker f$ and the linearity and bijectivity of $f$ would lead us to a contradiction.

Comment: I dont see the contradiction. Do you mean $\dim \Im f + \dim \ker f > \dim V$?

Comment: Call $n=\dim V$. As $f$ is injective $\dim\ker f=0$, and as $f(V)$ is a proper vector subspace $\dim f(V)<n$. This leads thus to the contradiction $n<n$.

Comment: OK now its clear. Thank you. One more thing: how do you know that f (from above) is also surjective?

Comment: You're welcome!:) Which $f$?

Comment: The $f$ defined in your answer.

Comment: If $v\in\text{Span}\{e_i\}_{i\in I\setminus J}$ then we can write $v=\lambda_{i_1}e_{i_1}+\cdots+\lambda_{i_k}e_{i_k}$. What is $f(\lambda_{i_1}e_{\phi^{-1}(i_1)}+\cdots+\lambda_{i_k}e_{\phi^{-1}(i_k)})$?

Comment: Ok. It's in fact every vector in the subspace?

Comment: Yes; the $v$ in the lasy comment was arbitrary.

Comment: I was worried that maybe you didn't accept my answer because you still had something unclear and having a look at your profile I've noticed that you have never accepted any answer. I encourage you to do so with the questions which have received a satisfactory answer. It is just about contributing to the community. Please consider it.

Comment: Oh yes, I have accepted. But please can you elaborate more on subjectivity. I think I did not got the point.

Comment: I was not looking for you to accept my answer if you still have any concerns about it, I just wanted you to consider helping the community grow by accepting answers when _they_ satisfy you. Also, I didn't understand that last comment; what is it you don't understand about my answer?

Comment: Your answer was really good, so thank you again. Thats why I accepted it. I have problems to understand the part about the subjectivity of $f$. Why is you constructed function surjective?

Comment: Ahhh, you mean the _surjectivity_ of $f$!! I think you are getting lost at some easy point so let me be more precise. The function $f$ is defined for every $v\in V$ (because $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis) and returns a vector $f(v)$ which (by definition of $f$) is a linear combination of a finite number of elements in $\{e_i\}_{i\in I\setminus J}$; i.e. $f(v)\in\text{Span}\{e_i\}_{i\in I\setminus J}$. So the range of $f$ is included in $\text{Span}\{e_i\}_{i\in I\setminus J}$. To see that we actually have an equality here (i.e. that $f$ is surjective from...

Comment: $V$ to $\text{Span}\{e_i\}_{i\in I\setminus J}$) we must check that for every $w\in\text{Span}\{e_i\}_{i\in I\setminus J}$ there exist some $v\in V$ such that $f(v)=w$: by definition we can write $w=\lambda_{i_1}e_{i_1}+\cdots+\lambda_{i_k}e_{i_k}$ for some scalars $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_k$ and some $e_{i_1},\ldots,e_{i_k}\in\{e_i\}_{i\in I\setminus J}$ and now $v:=\lambda_{i_1}e_{\phi^{-1}(i_1)}+\cdots+\lambda_{i_1}e_{\phi^{-1}(i_k)}$ satisfies $f(v)=w$ so we are done.

Comment: Aaaaaah thx :) great!